# how to use intialDelay and cron job in schedule annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, timer, cron

I want to create a time in Spring Boot which should start first at after 5 mins from java start (initialDelay) and from next time it should run at 5 AM of everyday

I am trying to use below code, but Tomcat stopped and Java is not starting.

```
@Service
public class ServiceHandler {
   @Scheduled(initialDelay = 5 * 60 * 100, cron = "0 0 5 * * *")
    public void SomeTimer() {
    //some code
    }
}
```

Main Spring Boot class:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Scheduled(initialDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000, cron = "0 0 5 1/1 * ? * ") though I am not sure if it will work as initialDelay and cron wont run together as there is possibility of cron running exactly when your server starts so in that case how spring will decide to wait or run cron ? so try to use fixed delay or fixed rate or just use cron.

Comment: @prasannajoshi but bro as per my requirement how to achieve them, even i kept separate schedule methods for cron and fixedDelay and it is also stoping the tomcat

Comment: any error ? can you remove fixed delay all together and try this  (cron = "0 0 5 1/1 * ? * ") only

Comment: if i remove initial delay it is working fine bro, but need to call a method after 5 mins for that i used initial delay

Comment: do u need every time or only once that initial delay ? if its only once then do Thread.sleep(for 5 min )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example:

```
@Component
public class SimpleScheduler {

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        process();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 17 * * ?")
    public void cron() {
        process();
    }

    private void process() {
        System.out.println("RUN");
    }
}
```

Consider to add @EnableScheduling to your application runner class.